# MySQL Query Syntax Error. Trying to create daily event but syntax error on simple query

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create an event that is performed everyday at 00 HRS forever. I cannot figure out what syntax error I have made.
My code:

```
delimiter |

CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS schedule_updation
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
STARTS CURRENT_DATE()
DO
  ALTER TABLE `bookings` DROP COLUMN `Date1`;
  ALTER TABLE `bookings` CHANGE `Date2` `Date1` TEXT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NULL;
  ALTER TABLE `bookings` CHANGE `Date3` `Date2` TEXT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NULL;
  ALTER TABLE `bookings` CHANGE `Date4` `Date3` TEXT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NULL;
  ALTER TABLE `bookings` CHANGE `Date5` `Date4` TEXT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NULL;
  ALTER TABLE `bookings` CHANGE `Date6` `Date5` TEXT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NULL;
  ALTER TABLE `bookings` ADD `Date6` TEXT after `Date5`;

  delimiter ;
```

The error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ALTER TABLE `bookings` CHANGE `Date2` `Date1` TEXT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE ' at line 6
```

Database version:

- Server: Local Databases (127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP)
- Server type: MySQL
- Server version: 5.7.11 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
- Protocol version: 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the column is not declared NOT NULL UNIQUE, there should be no problem.
try

```
ALTER TABLE `bookings` CHANGE `Date2` `Date1` TEXT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci DEFAULT NULL;
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE `bookings` CHANGE `Date2` `Date1` TEXT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci null default null;
```

Comment: You hit the nail on the head, thanks a lot. But it is giving me a duplicate column error when I try to change Date2 to Date1, I just created different events for each query for now. Thanks again though.

Answer (score 0):

an event `DO` can only have a single "statement" as its body. if you want multiple statements, you need to have a `BEGIN`/`END` block;

```
CREATE...
DO single_statement;
```

or

```
CREATE ...
DO BEGIN
    statement1;
    statement2;
    ...
END
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Marc B, but it gives an error when I use END saying 'Unrecognized statement type (Near END)' and a red cross besides it. No error for begin though.

Comment: yeah, sorry,  should be `END |`, since you changed the delimiter.

Comment: Still getting an error, but my entire event is flawed anyway so never mind. Thanks for the help though. :)